# The best cordova plugin to use Mixpanel

Tags: ionic-framework

Which cordova plugin I can use in ionic platform to use mixpanel services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm currently using this one: https://github.com/samzilverberg/cordova-mixpanel-plugin

it works for my needs.